# Maximum table (ListObject) size in Excel

Tags: excel

I've developed an Excel solution for one of my clients that revolves around a large table (up to column DI).  It's filled with about 25% data and 75% formulas.  When we now paste in 43000 rows of data, Excel 2010 starts moaning and croaking.  After saving of the workbook and re-opening it, Excel takes a long time and finally tells the workbook is corrupt.

I've already ruled out the possibility that we started with a corrupt workbook to begin with; I've started up a fresh workbook with a fresh like-sized table, added 43000 rows of data (this went fast), and added all formulas one by one (by copying the formula text, not just copy/pasting the cells).  After saving and re-opening the workbook, it is again corrupt.

I've tried 10000 rows, and that went fine.  around 18000 rows the problem raises it's ugly head again.  I also removed all formatting in the table, but that made no difference.

Is this a known issue?  Do any of you know if there's a safe rows/cells/complexity limit for tables?  Should I post a bug report with Microsoft or is this self-inflicted? :)

ADDED

Thanks to @Jeeped I've investigated how this behaves using the .XLSB format, and under that format the files are fine.  Re-saving back as .XLSX and the file is instantly "corrupt" again - i.e. Excel actually crashes on opening it.  The XML for the worksheet itself seems valid when checking it with XMLStarlet though (it contains 12.5 million elements); it's possibly a bug in Excel's loading routines?

Comment: ListObject (aka *'structured'*) tables have additional overhead but 43000 rows is not out of the question. Post a dozen rows of sample data together with the formulas used to get further attention. [hint:] save as an XLSB binary workbook to reduce file size (lots) and (marginally) increase calculation efficiency and get rid of your 32-bit Office installation in favor of a true 64-bit Office suite.

Comment: @Jeeped: that's what I thought as well...  64 bit Office is not up to me; the client already has 32 bit installed and cannot change this only for this solution (the workbook is meant to be split by another tool of mine and then distributed to 1000s of employees worldwide).  XLSB might indeed be a nice option here; I'll investigate and discuss it with my client.  And about the formula's: I'm working under an NDA, so I'll have to see what I can do there...  Thanks though for the heads-up about the size!

Comment: @Jeeped: saving as an xlsb also fixed the problem!  Somehow Excel hands out corrupt XML or such when saving as xlsx, because the xlsb file opened fine after saving.  Afterwards saving the xlsb as xlsx and reopening the file made Excel topple over again (it actually crashed during opening)...  So I think Excel just isn't up to this task when using xlsx; xlsb it's going to be.  Going to unpack the xlsx and see if I can spot an error (though the unpacked worksheet XML is 893MB big...)

Comment: I've tested opening the .xlsx in 32-bit Excel 2007; it errored, though it didn't crash.  Also tested in Excel 2003 with the .xlsx converter - it told me the converter couldn't convert the file.  I've got no possibility to test on 2013 or a 64 bit version, but that's no solution for me anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting with this a bit more I'm convinced it's a bug in Excel's loading routine.  When I push the table to a certain limit, the generated files will not open anymore, causing Excel to either crash or tell me the workbook is corrupt.  In the file mentioned in the question that limit occurred at about 20000 rows.  However:

- While saving as .xlsx meant the file got corrupt at, say, 20000 rows, saving it as .xlsb didn't really fix it but it pushed the limit up twofold to about 40000 (enough for this project, but still not satisfying).
- The number of columns in the table is important; the more columns the less rows I need for this to happen.
- The nature of the formulas in the columns is important; I had 4 columns with huge formulas (CHOOSE's with lots of arguments), and just removing those made the max row count go up with a factor 2.
- When a workbook is created that is just on the max row count, opening it from within Excel while another workbook is open causes Excel to error, while closing Excel and opening it from Explorer doesn't cause Excel to error.

So, I guess there is no resolution other than to hope Microsoft will fix this one day, and apply workarounds in the meanwhile.